# Can all Asynchronous tasks read a ArrayList at sametime without anydelay

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

In my Android app, I have a arrayList as mentioned below.

```
Public List<String> prefCoinList = new ArrayList<String>() ;
```

I will be executing 10 asynchronous task using THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR as mentioned below.

```
new asyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, order);
```

Each asynchronous task will **only** read the arrayList "prefCoinList" and checks for a particular value.

**Question**

1. Will all the 10 Asynchronous task will run without any deadlocks on the arrayList "prefCoinList" ?
2. Any thread locks / hanging issue will be there ?
3. If reading the arraylist at same time possible then will each thread get their own copy (or) all thread will wait and read the arraylist when they get their turn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is not modified after construction then you can access it from multiple threads without issue. Each thread will read the single copy of the object.

If the list is modified occasionally then you could use a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) or other access control mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

Let me asnwer each question.
1) Yeah, all 10 asynchronous calls will run without any problem, it is not a lot of info to be process.

2)You will not have thread locks, you only have to take care of use runOnUIThread because at that moment it stops the asynchronous call.

3) Java functions work passing the reference of the object. So, you have two options. You can pass to your asynchronous function the same array but you can't modify it, or you can create  a copy of the array to each function to avoid problems.

Comment: Your point `3)` is not correct. Java passes object parameters by reference.